# Chapter heading in Word is not the same

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I set `Heading 1` style for the chapter heading in Word. The style is as follows: Paragraph before 72 and after 54. I also use the word "Chapter" before the number of the chapter.

So if I place the cursor at the beginning of the page and click the `Heading 1` style, it will look like:

> Chapter 1 (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
>
> Introduction
>
> (Texts)...

Now, at the end of Chapter 1, I insert a page break and a blank page appears. I click `Heading 1` again, and it shows:

> Chapter 2
>
> Literature Review

Note that the words "Introduction" and "Literature Review" are entered manually.

My question is, I expect Chapter 2 will follow the paragraph style that I defined (i.e. Before 72, after 54) but it doesn't. Chapter 2 is displayed at the very top without following the Heading 1 paragraph style. Other settings like font are OK.

How do you deal with this problem? I tried to manually set this paragraph style, but the Chapter 2 is always displayed without the 'before' and 'after ' style.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Word 2010 suppresses space above headings at the top of the page, if they come after a Page Break (shift+enter).

If instead you use Section Break (Next Page) in Page Layout > Breaks > Next Page, then the space should not be suppressed before the Chapter 2 heading.